# Does ARC mean I should declare static types rather than id?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

The ARC document is publicly available on the LLVM site, so NDA is not an issue here.

I find that in getting my code ready for ARC, I am using (NSObject*) in a lot of situations where I would have formerly used (id).

For example, if I were writing an initWithParent: method, it might be

```
-(id) initWithParent: (NSObject*) parent;
```

where I would formerly have written

```
-(id) initWithParent: (id) parent;
```

My question is -- does this practice make sense?

Comment: I don't know why -(id) initWithParent: (id) parent; is failing with ARC. What is the issue you're seeing?

Comment: As Josh says, it seems like using `id` should work.  Is there toll-free bridging, a (void *) pointer, or a struct involved here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that will work for most cases, at least if your object derives from NSObject (which not quite everything does). [Here's an interesting blog post on the subject](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2008/03/id-vs-nsobject-vs-id.html) (independent from ARC).

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means any expert but it seems like it might run into trouble if the message passes something that is not an object (int, struct, etc…).

Other than that, it's an interesting way of getting around things.

Comment: If you are passing something that is not an object into a method expecting an `id`, that would seem to be a problem by itself.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I've never tried to pass something to id that wasn't an object so I didn't know the compiler wouldn't let you…